# Localhost, Php artisan serve and homestead Pro/Cons

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I am new to laravel and I am confused which environment I will used to create an app w/ db integration (MYSQL).

- Wamp (Localhost)
- PHP artisan
- Homestead

What are the pro/cons of each environment? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is opinion based, my answer will be based on my experience.

**WAMP (Localhost)**
Wamp is short for Window Apache Mysql PHP

***Pros:***
- Wamp can easily be setup on windows by installing Wamp server, EasyPHP e.t.c

- Can easily be configured
- Comes with PHPMyAdmin for quick Mysql database administration

***Cons:***

- Setting up Laravel in Wamp is a big pain as it involves advance configuration else you end up with URL 
  e.g http://localhost/project/public
- I have tried installing Memcached without success on Wamp; which is a good caching server for PHP/Laravel

**PHP Artisan**

***Pros:***

- Easy to use
- clean URL without /public

***Cons:***

- You still have to install PHP and Mysql to make it work
- Should be used for small Laravel project
- some other limitations

**Homestead**

This is the preferred development environment for Laravel

***Pros:***

- Installs everything you need to start developing Laravel app
- share a folder between your host
- can easily be rebuilt

***Cons:***

- I noticed each time shutdown my host system without properly saving homestead, I have to provision homestead each time to make it work which atimes requires internet connection
- there are some issues peculiar to Homestead that doesn't have specific solution you have to try a lot of things to resolve issue.
- Homestead seems to be slow atimes

**LNMP**

Linux (Ubuntu) Nginx Mysql PHP and virtualbox

This is my best development environment.
It takes minimum Linux experience to make this work but once achieved you will enjoy it.

***Pros:***

- fully customize and install anything you want such memcached, gulp, Mysql , PHP. Git, Just anything
- broaden your experience as a programmer do things yourself like system admin
- It hardly crash unlike homestead. You can always take snapshots in virtualbox
- easily move to a new system by coping virtual hard disk to another virtualbox

***Cons:***

- requires more effort to setup
- you need to have little Linux experience

These are just few of my experience which my answer is based upon.

Comment: Sure that what I am using right now. Google how to install PHP niginx Mysql on ubuntu 14.04. Look for tutorial from digitalocean thats how I was able to setup mine. You may also contact me on hangouts